# java date conversion gives a one day of the week earlier

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I m trying to parse a String containing date into Date object. But for some reasons I get one day earlier in the day of the week part.

```
private Date lineToDate(String line)
{
    Date date = new Date();
    try
    {
        DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy");
        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST"));
        date = sdf.parse(line);
        System.out.println(date.toString());
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return date;
}
```

When String "line" contains

```
"Mon Dec  3 03:21:31 2017 500 586 /"
```

the conversion returns

```
Sun Dec 03 03:21:31 IST 2017
```

I m  guessing there is some issue with the timezones . Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the third of December 2017 is a Sunday, not a Monday. You're probably looking at the wrong year, in 2013 it was on a Monday.

Comment: I was using a utility to generate the dates , It seems like there is a bug in it , may be it didnt take the leap year thing into consideration. Thanks :)